# How to use Mocha as hierarchical test suite?

Tags: gruntjs, mocha.js

I want to use Mocha as hierarchical test suite. I created a test for an API that is organized hierarchically like product -> add, product -> duplicate, product-> update, product -> delete.

I want to run tests with something like `mocha apis product`. This will run all the product related APIs as given above. And if I run `mocha apis product add`, it will run only the product -> add test case.

Answer (score 3):

Mocha already supports hierarchies. You just need to use the `describe` calls to build the top levels of the hierarchy:

```
describe("API", function () {
    describe("product", function () {
        it("add", function () {
        });

        it("delete", function () {
        });
    });

    describe("foo", function () {
        it("add", function () {
        });

        it("delete", function () {
        });
    });
});
```

Then you use `--grep` to narrow down which test you want Mocha to run. As the term "grep" implies the parameter you give with `--grep` is a regular expression.

With the file above, if I don't tell Mocha to run any specific test:

```
$ mocha --reporter spec
  API
    product
      ✓ add 
      ✓ delete 
    foo
      ✓ add 
      ✓ delete 


  4 passing (4ms)
```

I can narrow it to only product tests:

```
$ mocha --reporter spec --grep "API product"
  API
    product
      ✓ add 
      ✓ delete 


  2 passing (4ms)
```

And the add test for "product":

```
$ mocha --reporter spec --grep "API product add"
  API
    product
      ✓ add 


  1 passing (4ms)
```

Comment: Can you please guide me how to implement test suites using jenkins and mocha?